Setting Up a Powershell WebBrowser (Issues)
Using Powershell and the System.windows.forms assembly i am trying to create a working webbrowser that looks like any other webbrowser so i can get a custom webbrowser in an application. The Primary Issue is loading the objects on the webpage such as images or just some Out of Support Pages This is what i got so far.
add-type -assemblyname 'system.windows.forms'
$Form=[system.windows.forms.form]::New()
$TextBox=[System.windows.forms.Combobox]::New()
$Browser=[system.windows.forms.WebBrowser]::New()
$Browser.Location = '0,25'
$TextBox.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq 'Return' -or $_.KeyCode -eq 'Enter'){$Browser.Navigate($TextBox.Text)}})
$Form.StartPosition='CenterScreen'
$Browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed=$True
$Form.Add_ClientSizeChanged({$Browser.Size="$($Form.ClientSize.Width-100),$($Form.ClientSize.Height-50)"})
$Form.Controls.add($TextBox)
$Form.Controls.Add($Browser)
$Form.ShowDialog()

I Suppressed the Script Errors to stop the annoying Popups.
I was Expecting This To Be Just Like Every Other WebBrowser Out there And it just does not look good or load alot of the WebPage stuff that every other webBrowser Does.

Maybe try 'WebView2' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/

I was hoping to try to embed it directly into a forms webbrowser without having to use Microsoft-Edge Application. if Possible, Thanks Though
